# Struggling to find intersection between a rectangle and an edge in NetworkX and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I recently got tasked with creating a chart that displays relations between certain factions/countries in python.

To do this, I used NetworkX and matplotlib to visualize the data.

The data (for now, I'll integrate proper databases later) is stored in dictionaries in the following format:

```
countries_data = {
    "Country1": {"relations": {"Country2": "Ally", "Country3": "Enemy"}},
    "Country2": {"relations": {"Country1": "Ally", "Country3": "Neutral"}},
    "Country3": {"relations": {"Country1": "Enemy", "Country2": "Neutral"}},
    "Country4": {"relations": {"Country2": "Ally"}},
    "Country5": {"relations": {"Country2": "Enemy", "Country3": "Neutral"}},
    "Country6": {"relations": {"Country1": "Enemy", "Country2": "Ally"}},
}

alliances_data = {
    "Alliance1": {
        "color": "red",
        "members": ["Country1", "Country2", "Country3"],
        "relations": {"Alliance2": "Ally"}
    },
    "Alliance2": {
        "color": "blue",
        "members": ["Country4", "Country6"],
        "relations": {"Alliance1": "Ally"}
    }
}
```

Here's where things went downhill for me.
Everything went smooth until I had to connect edges between alliances that indicate their relationship.

[image: Figure 1]

I'm trying to get the edge that connects the alliances to connect on the edges of the rectangles that indicate the edges, and not their centers.

I created a function that calculates calculates the intersection points:

```
def isintersecting(w, h, linec):
    #linec=
    #0 = linex1, 1= linex2, 2= liney1, 3= liney2
    slope = (linec[2] - linec[3])/(linec[0] - linec[1])

    intersected = False
    if -h/2 <= slope*w/2 <= h/2:
        intersectedsofar = True
    
    if -w/2 <= (h/2)/slope <= w/2:
        intersectedsofar = True
    else:
        intersectedsofar = False

    if intersectedsofar == True:
        return [linec[1] + (w/2), linec[3] + (h/2)]
    else:
        return False
```

The following draws points at the two calculated intersection points.

```
for alliance, alliance_data in alliances_data.items():
    for other_alliance, relation in alliance_data["relations"].items():
        if alliance in alliance_pos and other_alliance in alliance_pos:
            print(f"Alliance {alliance} and Alliance {other_alliance} "
                  f"relation coordinates: {alliance_pos[alliance]}, "
                  f"{alliance_pos[other_alliance]}")
            for alliancerect in sillyarray:
                linecoordinate = [alliance_pos[alliance][0],
                                  alliance_pos[alliance][1], 
                                  alliance_pos[other_alliance][0],
                                  alliance_pos[other_alliance][1]]
                intersect = isintersecting(alliancerect[2], alliancerect[1], 
                                           linecoordinate)
                print(f"HE INTERSECT AT {intersect} "
                      f"WITH ALLIANCE {alliancerect[0]}")

                # Drop a point on the intersection coordinates
                if intersect:
                    plt.scatter(*intersect, color='green')
                    plt.text(intersect[0], intersect[1], f"{intersect}", 
                             fontsize=12)
```

[image: Figure 2]

Here's a hastebin of the full code; https://hastebin.com/share/aromasigup.python

Lastly, if anyone has a far better method of doing this; let me know.
My final goal is creating a chart that looks somewhat like this but more refined:

[image: Figure 3]

*(Data in chart removed for privacy reasons)*
In fact, if anyone can tell me what library was the upper image likely created in, I'll gladly abandon my current code and work with the newer library.
I'm still fairly new to networking and data, so if anyone here has a different and/or better approach, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is a bit over-engineered for your use-case but it allows to connect arbitrary patches (in your case rectangles) with either straight or Bezier lines without patch-line overlaps.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.bezier import (
    find_control_points,
    split_path_inout,
    inside_circle,
)


class Line:

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = np.array(points, dtype=float)


    def __call__(self, fractions):
        fractions = np.atleast_1d(fractions)
        return np.squeeze(
            self.points[0][np.newaxis, :] + fractions[:, np.newaxis] * (self.points[-1] - self.points[0])[np.newaxis, :]
        )


    def split(self, fraction):
        pivot = self.__call__(fraction)
        return (Line(np.vstack([self.points[0], pivot])),
                Line(np.vstack([pivot, self.points[-1]])))


    def remove_overlap(self, path, search_interval=(0.01, 1), tol=0.001, maximum_iterations=20):
        """Find the intersection between the line and an overlapping
        closed path and return a new, shorter instance of the line
        that does not overlap.

        """

        minimum, maximum = search_interval
        assert (minimum == 0) ^ (maximum == 1), \
            "The search interval has to include either end point of the line but not both."
        assert path.contains_point(self.__call__(minimum)) ^ path.contains_point(self.__call__(maximum)), \
            "The line does not intersect the path within the given search interval."

        # bisection
        if maximum == 1:
            completed_iterations = 0
            while (maximum - minimum > tol) & (completed_iterations < maximum_iterations):
                midpoint = minimum + (maximum - minimum) / 2
                if path.contains_point(self.__call__(midpoint)):
                    maximum = midpoint
                else:
                    minimum = midpoint
                completed_iterations += 1

            left, right = self.split(midpoint)
            return left

        else: # minimum == 0:
            completed_iterations = 0
            while (maximum - minimum > tol) & (completed_iterations < maximum_iterations):
                midpoint = minimum + (maximum - minimum) / 2
                if path.contains_point(self.__call__(midpoint)):
                    minimum = midpoint
                else:
                    maximum = midpoint
                completed_iterations += 1

            left, right = self.split(midpoint)
            return right


class BezierLine(Line):

    def __init__(self, coordinates, control_points=None):
        """Represent an arbitrary path as a Bezier curve.

        Arguments
        ---------
        coordinates : array-like
            Ordered iterable of evenly sampled (x, y) path coordinates. Ignored if valid :code:`control_points` are provided.
        control_points : array-like or None (default None)
            Ordered iterable of (x, y) control points. If None, the control points are computed based on the give coordinates.

        Attributes
        ----------
        control_points: np.array
            The control points defining the Bezier line.
        path : matplotlib.path.Path
            The matplotlib path object.
        segments: np.array([matplotlib.bezier.BezierSegment])
            List of matplotlib Bezier segments.

        """

        if control_points is None:
            coordinates = np.array(coordinates)
            assert len(coordinates) % 2, "The number of coordinates has to be odd!"
            self.control_points = self._find_control_points(coordinates)
        else:
            assert len(control_points) % 2, "The number of control points has to be odd!"
            self.control_points = np.array(control_points)

        self.path = Path(self.control_points, [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.CURVE3] * (len(self.control_points) - 1))
        self.segments = np.array([segment for segment, code in self.path.iter_bezier() if code > 1])


    def _find_control_points(self, coordinates):
        control_points = coordinates.copy()
        for ii in range(1, len(coordinates)-1, 2):
            c1, m, c2 = coordinates[[ii-1, ii, ii+1]]
            c1, cm, c2 = find_control_points(*c1, *m, *c2)
            control_points[ii] = cm
        return control_points


    def __call__(self, fractions):
        fractions = np.atleast_1d(np.array(fractions) * len(self.segments))
        indices = np.clip(fractions.astype(int), 0, len(self.segments)-1)
        remainders = fractions - indices
        out = []
        for index, remainder in zip(indices, remainders):
            if remainder < 0:
                out.append(self.segments[0](remainder))
            elif remainder >= 1:
                out.append(self.segments[-1](remainder))
            else:
                out.append(self.segments[index](remainder))
        return np.squeeze(out)


    def split(self, fraction):
        origin = self.control_points[0]
        pivot = self.__call__(fraction)
        distance = np.linalg.norm(pivot - origin)
        path_start, path_end = split_path_inout(self.path, inside_circle(*origin, distance))
        return (BezierLine(None, path_start.vertices),
                BezierLine(None, path_end.vertices))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    r1 = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 2, 1, facecolor="white", edgecolor="red")
    r2 = plt.Rectangle((0, 3), 2, 1, facecolor="white", edgecolor="blue")
    ax.add_patch(r1)
    ax.add_patch(r2)
    ax.autoscale_view()

    # initialize line connecting rectangle centers
    def get_center(r):
        x, y = r.xy
        return x + r.get_width() / 2, y + r.get_height() / 2

    c1 = get_center(r1)
    c2 = get_center(r2)
    line = Line([c1, c2])

    # remove overlaps at both ends
    p1 = r1.get_path().transformed(r1.get_patch_transform())
    line = line.remove_overlap(p1, search_interval=(0, 0.5))
    p2 = r2.get_path().transformed(r2.get_patch_transform())
    line = line.remove_overlap(p2, search_interval=(0.5, 1))

    # plot line
    ax.plot(*line([0, 1]).T, color="red")
    plt.show()
```